# Convert online mp3 files to base64 in react native

Tags: react-native

I found I need to base64 convert mp3 online to get duration of mp3, but I tried to use Filereader.readAsDataURL but it doesn't convert.

```
 async function Getduration(musicurl) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    let blob = await fetch(musicurl).then(r => r.blob());
    const buffer= reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    console.log(bufferStr)
    
  }
```

Next, we will use [react-native-get-mp3-duration](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-get-mp3-duration) to get the duration.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a FileReader you must be sure that it is loaded and attach your handler to the onload event. Your base64 string will be e.target.result

```
const fileReader = new FileReader();
let base64;
fileReader.onload = (e) => {
  base64 = e.target.result;
  // do stuff with base64 string
};

fileReader.readAsDataURL(blob);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.